# Eth0 not showing in Ubuntu 18 Desktop

Tags: static, ip, ip-address, ubuntu-18.04, static-ip-address

I want to assign a static IP address in Ubuntu using `eth0` port. But when I run `ifconfig`, eth0 is not there:

[image]

How will I assign a static address to `eth0`?